# how to compile github project source code into a .exe using clang and or gcc

Tags: c++, compilation

I am an artist and would like to have access to Monster Mash (https://github.com/google/monster-mash) even if I can't access the web version due to connectivity issues. As such I would like a desktp version, from what I have read on the github page I would just have to compile the code, but I have no idea how I would go about doing this on a windows machine as I am having trouble with downloading or setting up clang or gcc to begin with (Is gcc only for use on Linux). The Linux approach seems much simpler and is (to my eyes) better explained on the github page, so as a side question, I would like to know if I can compile the program in linux for use on windows? thank you so much for any help.

Comment: The readme tells you how to build: [https://github.com/google/monster-mash#readme](https://github.com/google/monster-mash#readme)

Comment: I would expect it to be more difficult to accomplish on windows unless you use msys2 which can install some of the dependencies for you. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: ***I am having trouble with downloading or setting up clang or gcc to begin with*** If you are in that situation you need to solve that first and practice using the tools on smaller and simpler projects. I expect you are at least a few days before you get up to speed to even begin building this.

Comment: Here's how you install MSYS2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: @drescherjm and HolyBlackCat thank you so much for pointing me towards msys. So far I have gcc set up in msys after following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXF4A5UeSeM youtube video. I also have followed the instructions for placing the Triangle source code in the third party folder as mentioned in the readme.  However, I am now stuck on the proper way to install sdl library v. 2.0, is this something I would do through msys? Thank you so much for the help, I am very greatful. P.S I agree that this is definetly going to be more than I can chew with my current knowledge